# Automation Script: If FieldA = 1, then set FieldB to 'one'

Tags: python, configuration, jython, maximo, jython-2.7

*I'm trying to break down this problem into manageable parts: [Spatial query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587515/maximo-spatial-query).*

---

I think the first step is to create an **automation script** that does this:

- Takes a value from a field
- Does something with it
- Returns a value to a different field

For example:

1. Create a new work order
2. Manually enter the `WONUM` as `1`
3. Save
4. The action of saving automatically triggers an automation script
5. The script checks to see if the `WONUM = 1`
6. If true, then the `DESCRIPTION` is populated with the word `one`

**How can I do this?**

(*Maximo 7.6.1.1*)

Comment: IBM has a Maximo automation script guide, called "Scripting with Maximo.pdf", that can be useful for simple scenarios such as this. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a#fullpageWidgetId=W5f281fe58c09_49c7_9fa4_e094f86b7e98&file=83c7752c-a621-4af9-bb32-d6ba7d612ab2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to set the `DESCRIPTION` to one when `WONUM` is set to 1.

Launch Point Details:

1. **Launch Point Type:** [Object Launch Point](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mt.doc/autoscript/c_obj_lp.html)
2. **Object:** `WORKORDER`
3. **Event:** Save
4. **Save:** Add (Before Save)

[image: Launch Point Screenshot]

Python Code:

```
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
wonum = mbo.getString("WONUM")
if wonum == "1":
    mbo.setValue("DESCRIPTION","one",MboConstants.NOACCESSCHECK)
```

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: For performance reasons, I would have an Object Event Condition of `:wonum=1` to prevent the script from executing unless it was going to do something.