# Populating a Maximo field using a db function: Why is this a bad practice?

Tags: function, configuration, customization, maximo

In a separate SO question, I asked how to populate a Maximo field using a db function:

[Take value from FieldA, send to a db function, and return value to FieldB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460154/take-value-from-fielda-send-to-db-function-return-value-to-fieldb/56465075?noredirect=1#comment99844979_56465075)

A Stack Overflow community member was kind enough to answer the question and provided this advice:

> And all that said, you should just use the automation script to do
> what you have the database function doing, if at all possible. **To be
> more blunt, what you are wanting to do is not considered good
> practice.** So, make sure to include in your script's comments your
> justification for not following good practice.

If we assume that there aren't any out-of-the-box methods for doing what I want ([Spatial Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587515/maximo-spatial-query)), then **why would referencing a database function from Maximo be a bad practice?**

*(Bear in mind that I'm new to the IT industry. I would benefit from layman's terms.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can be a little verbose, so I'll apologize up front for that. And it may seem like I'm wandering, but I'll try to bring it back together at the end.

As I said in my answer to your first question, [Take value from FieldA, send to db function, return value to FieldB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460154/take-value-from-fielda-send-to-db-function-return-value-to-fieldb/56465075?noredirect=1#comment99844979_56465075), calling a stored procedure (or stored function or whatever) from an automation script is not "good" practice. That isn't to say, dogmatically, that it shouldn't **ever** be done, but to say that, as a rule, it should be avoided. When making an exception to the good practice rule is the best way to solve a particular problem, your code should document why you chose (or were forced) to make an exception. And I stand by that answer to your first question, which made no mention of a special circumstance.

If there are no out-of-the-box configuration options for doing what you want, such as crossovers or relationships or domains or etc in Maximo, then your next option should be in-product customization options (also known as "small 'c' customizations), if they exist. It so happens that in the case of Maximo you have "automation scripting" or "autoscripting" in Python or JavaScript, with all (Java) classes in the JVM's / server's classpath at your disposal (possibly including Maximo Spatial's Java class methods), for an in-product customization option. Using examples from [Maximo 76 Scripting Features](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/03ad118c-6040-43dd-bc6d-d7a03510d135/attachment/5b9f2379-83a3-4a9f-8584-7920757fc141/media/Scritping76Features.pdf), you can even figure out how to call RESTful APIs, like those exposed by ESRI's ArcGIS, over HTTP or HTTPS.

If in-product (small "c") customizations don't work don't work well enough (such as causing performance problems), then it is generally acceptable, though not supportable, to customize the product itself (aka a big "C" customization). (Generally acceptable, as many companies would accept that rationale for developing a big "C" customization, but not supportable, as the vendor will ask you to remove your Customization and reproduce your problem if a problem is found and if it is at all conceivable that your Customization could be contributing to the problem in any way.) In the case of Maximo, writing your own Java classes or stored procedures are generally considered big "C" customizations.

In the case of Maximo, and you could probably generalize that to any COTS product, updating Maximo data from a stored procedure is considered exceptionally bad practice. This is because such updates are not subjected to Maximo's business rules and logic, which can lead to data integrity problems, support problems, and more. In particular, triggers often assume that Maximo has made database updates in a particular order (parent data being inserted before child data, for example) when its documentation explicitly disclaims commitment to such order. (If it doesn't anymore, it used to.)

All that in mind, if out of the box Maximo doesn't provide a configuration for doing what you need, and if you can't use autoscripting to do what you want, even with access to all of Maximo's and Java's libraries (in that order of preference), then it would be acceptable to use an automation script to call a database function to calculate a value for you to store via Maximo. In fact, in that scenario, calling a function from your script would be far better than having a trigger set the value, because, assuming you update Maximo via it's API, such as `mbo.setValue("attribute","value")`, your script will still leave the auditing, security, validation, data integrity, and other business rules in operation. As a bonus, any professional Maximo consultants (like me) you bring on to help with projects will waste less time (read: your money) trying to figure out what you are doing and why so they don't break it.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I still reference this answer from time to time. It's really good stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: @User1973 You're welcome. I'm glad you found it helpful, and I appreciate the time you took to say so.